# Nodejs - Mysql - Nested JSON Response

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I have a NodeJS Express API developed. I have a query and the respone of the query has to be send as nested response in the format mentioend below :

```
[
 {
  Status: Success,
  data:{
        "Key 1" : "Value1"
       },
       {
        "Key 2" : "Value2"
       }

  }
]
```

Key and value are obtained from mysql query which returns the response.

```
app.post('/getstatus', function(req, res){
    r1= req.body.imei;


    mysqlQuery = `SELECT value from table1 where key = true `;

    mysqlPool.query(mysqlQuery, function(error, response, fields){
        if(error){
            result = [{Status:"Error", Error: "Error Connecting to Database. Contact Administrator.", ErrorDetails:error.message }];

        }else{

            result=[{status:"Success", data:JSON.stringify(response)}];
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

I have tried the above code but it doesn't give me the response correctly. JSON.stringify(response) doesn't convert the data to JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else{

            result=[{status:"Success", data:response}];
        }
        res.json(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Why you used 'stringify'? res.json(result); will work, I think.

Comment: Hey, good point! Docs on re.json here https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json I didn't even look at OP's response method, just that they were using stringify in the wrong spot!

Answer (score 0):

Donot stringify the response at server side.
You should send it like a JSON and on user stringify it.

Comment: I think you're mistaking stringify for parse. Stringify makes a widely compatible string, and parse changes that into a JavaScript object. I'm not sure if the server can send a JavaScript object over http.